# Count Minutes of Last 7 Days in List

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 App (WINPRT XAML)**.

```
   public class AchievementsRecordType
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Minutes { get; set; }
        public int WorkOutID { get; set; }

    }
```

I made a **List** *AchievementsRecordList* of type *AchievementsRecordType* and added some dates in it with minutes information:

**Example:**

```
AchievementsRecordList.Add(new AchievementsRecordType { Date = DateTime.Today, Minutes = 7, WorkOutID = int.Parse(SelectedWorkoutID) });
```

**Output** of that list is for example:

> 18-09-2015, 7, 510 
>   20-09-2015, 7, 120
>
> 21-09-2015, 7, 433 
>   21-09-2015, 7, 437 
>   21-09-2015, 7, 438
>
> 24-09-2015, 7, 120 
>   24-09-2015, 7, 121
>
> 25-09-2015, 7, 340 
>   25-09-2015, 7, 341 
>   25-09-2015, 7, 342

Now today is 26-09-2015, How to calculate **total minutes of past 7 days**?

Answer (score 1):

```
 AchievementsRecordList
.Where(x=>x.Date >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7)&& x.Date < DateTime.Today)
.Sum(y=>y.Minutes);
```

Comment: I think you need to check ">=" rather than "<=". "<=" will give me all the day before past 7 days, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
lst.Where(x=>x.Date >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7) && x.Date <=DateTime.Today).Sum(x=>x.Minutes)
```

Comment: What about  && x.Date <=DateTime.Today?

Comment: I dont know if your data will contain something for future dates also or not. in case you want to calculate only for today and 7 days earlier, you need to have the upper bound check

Comment: Dark Night and your answer is logically same. he wants past seven days records. so obviously you do not need to check for x.Date <=DateTime.Today

Comment: for example today is 19th. and the data in records contains an entry for 22nd. if you say get me records which are only greater than 19-7, wont it also take the data for 22nd into account. To stop that, i have a check for dont take dates which are after today.